# How to sum TimeSpan's residing a GridView

Tags: c#, winforms

i could not sum time using Array.
i have one column in gridView which stored extra times of worker and i want sum all times and want get total hours and minutes how to do this please ?

```
 TimeSpan p = new TimeSpan();
  for ( int i = 0; i < grid_horas.Rows.Count; i++ )
  {

       //TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse(grid_horas.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString());

  }
```

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal how would that matter?

Comment: You could win the price to the worst formatted / expressed question of the day ...

Comment: Think about what you would like to do step by step... figure out how to get one timespan  out of grid, then get all, then add them together

Comment: I can't see what's so wrong about this question. 5 downvotes?

Comment: btw, there **is** no array here; the `[i]` and `[7]` are *indexers*, but not into arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `.Value` *is* a timespan, then it should just work as:

```
TimeSpan sum = TimeSpan.Zero;
for ( int i = 0; i < grid_horas.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
   sum += (TimeSpan)grid_horas.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;
}
// now use sum.Hours, sum.TotalHours, sum.Minutes etc
```